# FindViewById() returns null without compilation error

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer, baseadapter

App crashes and logcat gives a Nullpointer when i try to run my app:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

Can somebody pls help?

I am trying to put a listview with a Custom Adapter in my navigation drawer.

I think the problem is caused by trying to bind the adapter to the listview.
Thank you in advance.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);

    drawerFragment.setUp((R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer), (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

---

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;
    String[] socialSites;
    int[] images = {R.drawable.ic_1, R.drawable.ic_2, R.drawable.ic_3, R.drawable.ic_4, R.drawable.ic_5};
    public MyAdapter (Context context){
        this.context=context;
        socialSites=context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.social);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return socialSites.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return socialSites[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row =null;
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflator= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=inflator.inflate(R.layout.cutom_row, parent, false);
        }
        else{
            row=convertView;
        }
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView titleImageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        titleTextView.setText(socialSites[position]);
        titleImageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        return row;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="android.getgo.org.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="android.getgo.org.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView1" />

</fragment>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

Edit:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
}
```

Comment: You should probably update your question to something more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new layout file and call it fragment_navigation_drawer :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Update your OnCreateView accordingly :

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer,null);

        ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        MyAdapter  myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity());
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        return view;
    }
```

**You should move your MyAdapter code into a separate class or make it static and import it in your fragment.**

Comment: clean the project and retry

Comment: Son you have nested your listview in to a fragment as your xml file indicates. You have to create the fragment first and call this code from OnCreateView method of the fragment. Also it is discouraged to add fragments to the layout file.

Comment: @throws_exceptions_at_you out of curiosity, why is it discouraged? Could you provide some info (maybe official statements?)?

Comment: H, thx but i am really stuck now and confused.
Apologies but i am new to this.

Comment: I guess you will have this somewhere in your code base : public class NavigationDrawerFragment { ... } right ?  there you will find this method :  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ....
        }
Put your code there and repost your changes

Comment: Many thx and i applied your changes but i get 'cannot resolve method inflate(int)' on  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer);
Furthermore on MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity()); i get cannt resolve symbol 'MyAdapter'

Comment: Inflate is ok now but still cannot resolve 'MyAdapter' on MyAdapter  myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity());

Comment: Please see the last line of my edits. Don't forget to import the MyAdapter class.

Comment: Do i need to make a seperate class MyAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

put the listview initialisation before setAdapter

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);

    drawerFragment.setUp((R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer), (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Yes Longi, i put it inside the fragment of the .xml file

Comment: is the listview the root element?

Comment: oh, you have to create a seperate layout xml for fragments, you can't embed the layout in the 'fragment' tag. follow [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) , or if you're using android studio you can generate an empty fragment (or activity with fragment)

Comment: Hi Longi, indeed i`m using android studio.
I`m a bit lost now, can you show me pls?

Comment: oh now I realise you're trying to create a navigation drawer. You can generate an activity with a navigation drawer (Better yet, you can select the navigation drawer template when creating a new project), right click on application package (in which the source files are) select New>Activity>Navigation Drawer Activity, Android Studio will generate a template code for you that works out of the box. You can edit that code in whatever way you want to.

Comment: Hi Longi, the navigation drawer is already functioning, i didn`t new it existed as template in android srudio though.
So something else is missing, i generated a blank fragment activity class (BlankFragment), now how do i put this is the main code?